# Dialy Alarm code Explanation

Tags: android, calendar, alarmmanager

I am new to android , I want to make alarm that notify me dialy at 11am .I have found some code on net,But dont know some part of it. Below is code

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

Intent myIntent = new Intent(AndroidAlarmService.this, MyAlarmService.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AndroidAlarmService.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());  does
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10); 

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 5*1000, pendingIntent);

Toast.makeText(AndroidAlarmService.this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}});
```

can any one explain me what this two line does

```
 calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());  does
 calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
```

And also help me how can i set alarm that will notify me on the same time for example at 11am

Comment: This line means it get current time and add 10 seconds in it.

Comment: so how can i set alarm that notify me dialy at 11am

Comment: see my answer for this :)

Comment: Accept answer if it is work for u. this will help others

Comment: I have accepted your answer... Thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call this function where you need:

```
private void setDailyNotification(int ID, int hh, int mm, int ss) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(Dashboard.this, MyDailyReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent.putExtra("ID", ID);
    Log.d("setDailyNotification", "ID:" + ID);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            Dashboard.this, ID, alarmIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mEverydayPendingIntent = pendingIntent;

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hh);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mm);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, ss);

    // check whether the time is earlier than current time. If so, set it to
    // tomorrow. Otherwise, all alarms for earlier time will fire

    if (calendar.before(now)) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
            mEverydayPendingIntent);
    Log.d("setRepeated", "ID:" + ID);

}
```

**Broadcast receiver:**

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Daily Summery");
        mBuilder.setContentText("Today's Transaction");
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon);
        Log.d("tag1234", "In if" + daily_Reminder);
        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
        mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
        mNotificationMa = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationMa.notify(11, mBuilder.build());
```

call function like this:

```
setDailyNotification(11, 11,00, 00);
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.currentTimeMillis()`- gets the current time from the device.

`calendar.setTimeInMillis()`- sets the current time.

`calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10)` - adds ten seconds to the current time.

In total, you are fetching the current time of the device and adding ten seconds in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Worked for me

```
 int interval = 1000 * 60 * 1;
// 1 for minutes ,you can pass 60*24

//And set alarm manager like this

 Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(AlaramManagerActivity.this, NotificationReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent  pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlaramManagerActivity.this, RQS_1, alarmIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),interval, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);

  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Splash.this, 0,   myIntent, 0);

  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
  Calendar firingCal= Calendar.getInstance();
  Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();
  firingCal.set(Calendar.HOUR,11); // At the hour you wanna fire
  firingCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); // Particular minute
  firingCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); // particular second
  long intendedTime = firingCal.getTimeInMillis();
  long currentTime = currentCal.getTimeInMillis();
  if(intendedTime >= currentTime){ 
// you can add buffer time too here to ignore some small differences in        milliseconds
// set from today
 alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, intendedTime,        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
  } 
 else{
 // set from next day
 // you might consider using calendar.add() for adding one day to the current day
 firingCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
 intendedTime = firingCal.getTimeInMillis();
 alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, intendedTime,    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);}
```